# Extracting the dimension of an operator from algebra

Tags: operators, conformal-field-theory, dimensional-analysis, vector-fields, lie-algebra

I may misinterpret the question. In the lecture note of conformal field theory, [arXiv:2207.09474](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.09474), it says the following

[image]

where for $P^\mu=i\partial_\mu$ and $D=ix^\mu \partial_\mu$. I am confused whether we can say anything about the dimension of $P^\mu$ or $K^\mu$ solely from the commutation
$$
[D,P^\mu]=-iP^\mu\; \text{and}\; [D,K^\mu]=iK^\mu
$$

Is the question valid? Can we extract the dimension of $P$ and $K$ from the commutation relations?

Comment: Don't use images for math. Use MathJax instead.

Comment: You may rescale P and K as you wish, but once you pegged D and P, the commutation relations "remind" you of the dimension of K and M.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the dila(ta)tion operator $D/i=x^{\mu} \partial_{\mu}$ is a Euler vector field that literally counts the length dimension for operators made from only $x^{\nu}$ and $\partial_{\lambda}$.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we extract the dimension of $P$
> and $K$
> from the commutation relations?

The answer is no as, dimensionally, $P$ and $K$ cancel out of those equations.